# Reactive pattern (Vuex, Redux, flux)

Tags: redux, vuex

I am wondering what the best practices are for editing values in the store.

Lets say I have a simple object in my store.

```
state: {
    name: '',
    email: '',
    isHuman: true
}
```

is it ever okay to just bind directly to these properties so that when I edit something in my component it directly makes changes to these properties? Or is it better practice to ALWAYS go through an action/reducer action/mutation?

Comment: well I know to use a store, I am just wondering if it is okay to bind directly to the values in the store or should I go through an action -> mutator to edit the store value

Comment: Basically, you should use a mutator as well to make the value change in the store.

Comment: You could assign directly some value when you initiate your app. But on the fly, you should do it through actions/mutations. Some guys say they can directly make changes and app still works. Well, when his app is small and he does not need to debug or check anything.

Answer (score 0):

You always want to use an action/mutation when modifying state. This is how the store is able to predictably and reliably track changes and produce the reactivity you expect in your application.